# find within if statement in shell

Tags: shell, if-statement, find

I am trying to this simple task of checking if a file was created or updated in the last 15 mins and create one if it doesn't exist. But I get an error with find if the file doesn't exist.
Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
if [ -n "$(find test.txt -mmin +15)" ]
then
echo "old file found. needs touch up"
touch test.txt
else
echo "File modified in the last 15 mins jeez"
fi
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I get a `find: test.txt': No such file or directory` error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` interprets its "regular" arguments (those not starting with `-`) as paths in which to look. They can be dircectories or single files, but they do need to exist. You probably want to look in the current directory for a file *named* `test.txt`:

```
if [ -n "$(find . -name test.txt -min +15)" ]
```

(Depending on your implementation of `find`, you can omit the `.` argument.)

To make sure the file gets created if it doesn't already exist, just add a check for existence as well:

```
if ! [ -e test.txt ] || [ -n "$(find . -name test.txt -min +15)" ]; then
```

Comment: "Still didn't work" doesn't help diagnose what is wrong. The stray apostrophe in the error message you report is odd, though.

Comment: Hmm. It works fine if touch the file before running this snippet. So, if the file exists before hand it works. But doesn't if it has to create/touch the file.

Comment: Right; `find` won't report a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: The opening statement isn't quite accurate — if you specify an existing file, `find` is quite happy to work with it, but it won't recurse on a non-directory, of course.  I can see what you're driving at, but …

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do:

```
name="test.txt"
if [ ! -f "$name" ] && [ -n "$(find "$name" -mmin +15)" ]
then
    echo "Old file $name found. Needs touch up"
    touch "$name"
else
    echo "File $name modified in the last 15 mins jeez"
fi
```

or perhaps:

```
name="test.txt"
if [ ! -f "$name" ]
then
    echo "File $name does not exist"
elif [ -n "$(find "$name" -mmin +15)" ]
then
    echo "Old file $name found. Needs touch up"
    touch "$name"
else
    echo "File $name modified in the last 15 mins jeez"
fi
```

There's a small window between tests during which the file could be removed after it was detected as being present.  That's unlikely to be a real problem, but be aware that it could in theory happen (and if you run the script often enough — and the file ever goes missing — then it will eventually happen).